# How Do I Raise the Change Event in the KendoUI DatePicker?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-datepicker

I'm trying to set the value of my DatePicker using the code below and expecting the "Change" event to be raise but it doesn't.

```
var datePicker = $("#datePicker").data("kendoDatePicker");
var previousDate = new Date(datePicker.value());
previousDate.setDate(previousDate.getDate() - 1);
$("#displayDate").text(kendo.toString(new Date(previousDate), 'D'));
datePicker.value(previousDate);
```

Change the date value through the user interface does raise the "Change" event as expected however.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

HTML

```
<input id="datepicker" />
<input type="button" value="set date" onclick="setdateInDP()">
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    function onChange() {
        alert("Change :: " + kendo.toString(this.value(), 'd'));
    }

    $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
        change: onChange
    });
});

function setdateInDP() {
    var datePicker = $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker");
    var previousDate = new Date(datePicker.value());
    previousDate.setDate(previousDate.getDate() - 1);
    datePicker.value(previousDate);
    $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker").trigger("change");
}
```

Comment: The problem is that it won't trigger change on the input as it normally do when you select a date with the picker.  This gets done in the _change() function of datepicker...