# kendo datepicker change event doesn't refresh the month view

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a kendo date picker defined as follows:

```
<input id="datePicker" data-format="dd.MM.yyyy" data-month='{ "content": "&lt;span class=\"#= dateRange.hasReport(data.date) ? \"boldDate\" : \"normalDate\" #\"&gt;#=data.value #&lt;/span&gt;" }' data-role="datepicker" data-bind="value: new Date(), events: {change: dateChanged}" style="width:150px;" />
```

In the month template, I bold some dates depending on whether there is a report or not for that date by a call to the method dateRange.hasReport(data.date)

Now, there is an external event which causes the daterange to change. I want to now refresh the calender view so that the dateRange.hasReport is called for all dates again.

I am unable to find a way to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by destroying the element and recreating it again

```
$("#datePicker").data("kendoDatePicker").destroy();
$('#datePicker').empty();
createDatePicker(); //Creates the datepicker widget again
$("#datePicker").closest("span.k-datepicker").width(150);
```

Comment: You can post `createDatePicker();` function code as well. For future reference for some one.

Answer (score 1):

Use the methods min(), max() to change your ranges and the 'change' event will be triggered I guess. You can bind your function there if you want.

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/datepicker

Comment: +1 Yes, We can trigger the `change` event. But not sure it will update `month view`, Some how the Link reference content has been altered. So, Look at this thread [How do I trigger the Change Event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15716402/how-do-i-raise-the-change-event-in-the-kendoui-datepicker)